# How to fix CORS error For Response header

Tags: angular, yii2

I am using Angular7 as frontend and yii2 as backend app
When i try to call api from angular it gives error "XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/pwap/html/api/web/v2/users/login' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status."

I have applied different solution for CORS but not succeed

My htaccess code in Yii2 backend is like below

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
#Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "http://localhost:4200"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE"
Header set Access-Control-Max-Age "86400"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*"
Header set Access-Control-Request-Headers "*"
```

Angular code like below

```
        const httpOptions = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
              'Content-Type':  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8, application/json, text/html, text/plain , text/xml',
              'app_token': environment.app_token,
              'Accept': '*/*',
              'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': ['*'],
              //'Access-Control-Request-Headers': ['*'],
              'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': ['*']
            })
          };

        let data = {
            "username": username,
            "password": password
        }
        let params = new URLSearchParams();
        for(let key in data){
            params.set(key, data[key]) 
        }


        return this.http.post('http://localhost/pwap/html/api/web/v2/users/login', data, httpOptions)
            .pipe().subscribe(user => {
                // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
                if (user) {
                    console.log(user);
                    // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                    //this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
                }

                return user;
            }
            );
    }
```

also i have passed 'app_token' header which is not display in "Key:value" pair
[image]

Response Header [image]

[image]

Whats wrong i am doing here? Need a help

Comment: Show the response headers

Comment: Hi Pranoy Response Header added to Question

Comment: in your angular code change it to  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',

Comment: Changed 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': `['*']`, to 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': `'*'`, same error

Comment: Try to use nginx for reverse proxy. Thus CORS error can be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to go for the solution to set up a proxy configuration. Bypass the proxy using angular-cli. In this way, the one who talks with the API server is Angular CLI server.

Create a proxy config file in the project folder: proxy.config.json with the following content.

```
{
 "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://http://localhost/pwap/html/api/web/v2/users/login",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""}
  }
}
```

Now you can serve your app with the following command:

```
ng serve  —-proxy-config proxy.conf.json
```

Please Note that your requests have to go to 'localhost:4200/app/{resource name}'. For example, like this:

```
this.httpClient.post('api/users'));
```

For more [information...](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/the-best-ways-to-connect-to-the-server-using-angular-cli-b0c6b699716c)

Answer (score 0):

in api controller

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(parent::behaviors(), [
                'corsFilter' => [
                    'class' => yii\filters\Cors::className(),
                    'cors' => [
                        'Origin' => ['*'], // or your app adddress specified
                        'Access-Control-Request-Method' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'], 
                        'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => ['*'],
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => true
                    ]
                ]
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case it may be useful to save some long frustrating hours, I summarize here two solutions working for me, using Angular (v11.0.2) and Yii2 (v2.0.35).

**Authentication with username and password**

My `OauthController` looks like this:

```php
class OauthController extends Controller
{
    public static function allowedDomains() {
        return [
            'http://localhost:4200',
            'http://localhost:*',
            // '*',
        ];
    }

    public function behaviors() {
        return array_merge(parent::behaviors(), [

            // For cross-domain AJAX request
            'corsFilter'  => [
                'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::class,
                'cors'  => [
                    // restrict access to domains:
                    'Origin'                           => static::allowedDomains(),
                    'Access-Control-Request-Method'    => ['POST'],
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'     => ['Origin', 'X-Requested-With', 'Content-Type', 'accept', 'Authorization'], 
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => true,
                    'Access-Control-Max-Age'           => 3600,              
                ],
            ],

        ]);
    }
// ...
}
```

In Angular I login adding the headers `'Content-Type'` and `Authorization` (i.e. `BasicAuth`):

```
login(email: string, password: string) {
    let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    httpHeaders.append(
      'Authorization',
      'Basic ' + btoa(email + ':' + password)
    );

    const httpOptions = {
      headers: httpHeaders,
    };

    return (
      this.http
        .post<AuthResponseData>(
          "http://your-url",
          // Body
          {
            username: email,
            password: password,
          },
          httpOptions
        )
        .pipe(
          // ...
        )
    );
}
```

**Authentication with Bearer token**

As pointed out in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53188014/1630538) answer, Yii2 Bearer authentication may be hard to handle with frontend frameworks.

In my case any attempt using `HttpBearerAuth` failed and I use `QueryParamAuth` instead.

```php
class SomeController extends \yii\rest\ActiveController
{

    public static function allowedDomains() {
        return [
            // '*', // THIS WILD CARD MAY CREATE PROBLEMS (see notes below)
            'http://localhost:4200',
            'http://localhost:*',
            $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
        ];
    }

    public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => QueryParamAuth::class,
        ];

        $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
            'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::class,

            'cors'  => [
                'Origin'                           => static::allowedDomains(),
                'Access-Control-Request-Method' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'     => ['Origin', 'X-Requested-With', 'Content-Type', 'accept', 'Authorization'], 
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => true,
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => true,
                'Access-Control-Max-Age'           => 3600,
            ],
        ];

        return $behaviors;
    }
// ...
}
```

In Angular, I set the query param `access-token` in an `interceptor`:

```
let headers = req.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
const modifiedReq = req.clone({
  params: new HttpParams().set('access-token', user.token),
  headers: headers,
});
```

**Notes**

- By inspecting [prepareHeaders()](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/filters/Cors.php#L160) it is clear that the wild card `'*'` is allowed only if `'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'` is `false` or not set.
- The query parameter `access-token` is the definition of `$tokenParam` set by Yii2 in the `QueryParamAuth` class ([source code](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/filters/auth/QueryParamAuth.php#L21))
- If anyone knows how to make `HttpBearerAuth` work with Angular I would appreciate the help.